# Better way to check whether parameter in method is array or range

Tags: ruby

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def method(*parameters)
  ...code...
  return parameters
end
```

Input should be:

```
method(1, 2, 3)
method([1, 2, 3])
method(*[1, 2, 3])
method(1..3)
```

I want to get the same return value `[1, 2, 3]`.

Is there a good way to write this without a bunch of conditions?

Comment: `method(1, 2, 3)` is equivalent to `method(*[1, 2, 3])`. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @mudasobwa I want to write some filter method that choose from parameters(date list or range). I want it accepts array or range parameter

Comment: @JaehyunShin please see an update of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
▶ def m(*pars); puts "#{pars.class}: #{pars.inspect}" end
▶ m(1, 2, 3); m([1, 2, 3]); m(*[1, 2, 3]); m(1..3)
#⇒ Array: [1, 2, 3]      # OK
#⇒ Array: [[1, 2, 3]]    # not OK
#⇒ Array: [1, 2, 3]      # OK 
#⇒ Array: [1..3]         # not OK
```

That said, variants 1 and 3 (they are absolutely equivalent, as @sawa said in comments) are fine. The second one passes an array as the first parameter of `pars` array, yielding the superfluous nesting in result. The latter one has nothing to do with an intent, `Range` instance is by no mean an array. Whether one wants to pass range, it must be splatted:

```
▶ m(*1..3)
#⇒ Array: [1, 2, 3]      # OK
```

**The summing up**: *“I want it accepts array or range parameter”*:

```
▶ def m(*pars)
▷   pars = [*pars.first] if pars.size == 1
▷   puts "#{pars.inspect}"
▷ end
▶ m(1, 2, 3); m([1, 2, 3]); m(*[1, 2, 3]); m(1..3); m(*1..3)
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def method(*parameters)
  parameters.flat_map{|e| [*e]}
end

method(1, 2, 3)   # => [1, 2, 3]
method([1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]
method(1..3)      # => [1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
def method(*parameters)
  parameters.inject([]){|a, e| a.push(*e)}
end

method(1, 2, 3)   # => [1, 2, 3]
method([1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]
method(1..3)      # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def method(*parameters)
  case parameters.first
  when Range
    parameters = parameters[0].to_a
  when Array
    parameters = parameters[0]
  end
  parameters
end
```

Comment: `parameters = [*parameters.first] if pars.size == 1`